# How to run the coffeephysics engine on Terminal in ubuntu or windows?

Tags: ubuntu, terminal, coffeescript, executable

I found this new engine on the web called CoffeePhysics which is based on Coffeescript.

The working demo can be found here: http://soulwire.github.io/Coffee-Physics/

The code as seen is available on github.

I downloaded the source code with all the files that are present.

I tried different ways but was unable to run the code in order to get a working demonstration.

I was trying to get it working from Terminal in Ubuntu or from Windows but did not have any success.

If anyone could help in figuring out how to execute code it would be really helpful.

Thanks

Comment: It is JavaScript, meant to run in your browser (not in a "terminal").  I downloaded the files and was able to open the top-level index.html in Chrome and run the demo.